# Is there a way to allow the end user to sort a report when loaded in MS Access?

Tags: vba, sorting, ms-access, report, ms-access-2010

I made a report in Access with 2 key ways of sorting it - by date and by FG number. I want to leave the default sorting as by date, but still allow the user to toggle between the 2. Is there a way to do so on the report itself? I don't want the user to have to open two different reports and I think it would also simply look better to give the user the option to toggle.

**Method attempted per suggestion below**

```
Private Sub Report_Load()

    Me.OrderBy = "job_date"
    Me.Frame360 = 1

End Sub

Private Sub Frame360_Click()

    If Me.Frame360 = 1 Then
        Me.OrderBy = "job_date"
    Else
        Me.OrderBy = "FGNumber"
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There certainly is!

Create an Option Group in the header of your form. You can use the wizard for this, it's easier. Supply the two (or more) possible fields to sort by as Label Names. You can set a default choice, but this sometimes doesn't work on reports like it does on forms (don't worry, we will fix this later). On the next screen, leave the values as default (1, 2, ...). Then choose "Save the value for later use". I leave the style on radio buttons, but it's up to you. Mine is called `optSortBy`.

[image: As described above]

Then, in the `Report_Load()` event:

```
Private Sub Report_Load()

    Me.OrderBy = "Field1"
    Me.optSortBy = 1

End Sub
```

This sets the default value, and sorts by it.

Then, in the `On Click` event of the frame around your buttons:

```
Private Sub optSortBy_Click()

    If Me.optSortBy = 1 Then
        Me.OrderBy = "Field1"
    Else
        Me.OrderBy = "Field2"
    End If

End Sub
```

The last step is to set `Display When` of the frame to `Screen Only`, so it doesn't print with the report.

Comment: The `Display When`? No, it's in the Report properties, under `Format` (at the bottom). Did this solution work for you?

Comment: If you mean the two blocks of code, then yes they are done in VBA. On the Report properties, go to `Event` and make an `Event Procedure` for the `On Load` event. Put the code in there. The second one goes in the `On Click` event of the frame.

Comment: I tried your code but it didn't work. I built the Event Procedure for the OnClick by clicking on the actual frame surrounding the two options and finding "On Click" in properties. Then I pasted in the code for that and changed it to my option groups name (Frame360). When I try to view this in Report View, it prompts me for a parameter asking me to fill in a value for "Field2"

Comment: Field1 and Field2 are the names of the two fields in my table. You will have to change those in the code to the names of the fields you want to sort by. (If there is a space in the field name, enclose it in [square brackets]).

Comment: So now it looks like it is working, however Access keeps crashing. It seems to be happening whenever I hit F5 to refresh the report in Report View

Comment: That's odd, it shouldn't cause any crashes (my version behaves just fine when I hit F5). Have you tried compacting and repairing the database? If that doesn't help, perhaps try and make another report with nothing else on it but the two fields, the option group and this code, and see if that has the same issues?

Comment: Ok so I tried this on a brand new report and it worked just fine.....the sorting worked perfectly and I was able to hit refresh a bunch of times with no crash. And yes I tried compacting the database but it didn't fix the original report.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84720/discussion-between-mark-butler-and-whatwhatwhat).

Comment: It works now. I'm not sure what I did, but no crashes so far after 10 minutes of use. Thanks!